# как выровнять теги li?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю выравнивание всех трех тегов находящихся в одном Враппере, после чего не могу выровнять список, подскажите пожалуйста как сделать. спасибо

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
     <h1>Монтаж систем вентиляции и кондиционирования</h1>

     <ul>
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Работаем без предоплаты</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i>скидки до 40%</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-check"></i>бесплатный выезд инженера</li>
     </ul>
     <a href="" class="button">Отправить заявку</a>
    </div>
```

css вот такой

```css
 .header-content
  text-align: center
  h1
   font-size: 28px
   line-height: 30px
  ul
   li
    font-size: 16px
```

Comment: вам ответ тоже жипегом скинуть?

Comment: Покажите ваш html-код и css для этого кода.

Comment: Если вам дали нужный ответ, то можете отметить его как Правильный

Answer (score 3):

Скорее всего у вас у родительского блока стоит свойство `text-align: center`.

Если я правильно понял задачу то вам нужно сделать вот такую структуру `html`:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <ul>
        <li>Работаем без предоплаты</li>
        <li>Скидки до 40%</li>
        <li>Бесплатный выезд инженера</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

И задать стили обёртке в `css`:

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: left;
}

.wrapper ul {
  list-style: none;
}
```

Пример на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efwmuL1k/)

Answer (score 1):

теги li по умолчанию прибиты влево, видать проблема в родительском блоке ,посмотри значени text-align

Comment: Да все верно, для родительского тега стоит text-align: center потому что мне нужно выравнять h1 и баттон, и сам список я хлчу чтобы тоже был посередине, но галочки в один ряд. Если я задаю text-align: left для ul или li, он толкает мне список к левому краю, а это не нужно

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то это можно сделать так:

```css
    .wrapper {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .wrapper ul {
      display: inline-block;
      text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <ul>
        <li>Работаем без предоплаты</li>
        <li>Скидки до 40%</li>
        <li>Бесплатный выезд инженера</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите выровнять только галочки, а текст оставить по центру, то вам помогут `flex`, псевдоэлементы и абсолютное позиционирование.

```css
.header-content {
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 30px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 16px;
}
ul li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: "\f00c";
  font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free";
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
  display:inline-block;
  font-style:normal;
  font-variant:normal;
  text-rendering:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="header-content">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <h1>Монтаж систем вентиляции и&nbsp;кондиционирования</h1>

    <ul>
      <li>Работаем без предоплаты</li>
      <li>Скидки до 40%</li>
      <li>Бесплатный выезд инженера</li>
    </ul>
    <br>
    <a href="" class="button">Отправить заявку</a>
  </div>
</div>
```